# safari "find" does not work for partial word

Tags: macos, safari

Sorry but I don't know how to describe this problem. Let's see a simple example below.

Take [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222197/using-vim-effectively-with-ruby-rails/17223250#17223250) as an example, when I search(cmd+F) "comp", safari is able to find everything about it; but if I search "omp", nothing can be found! (suppose I want to find strings containing "complete")

This can be inconvenient sometimes because I may forget the spelling of the first several letters of a word/string, or I may be only concerned about the postfix, namely, finding all strings with a given postfix(or 'midfix') and the prefix can be arbitrary.

Can someone explain this issue and is there a way to resolve it ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by design. Clicking on the magnifying glass next to your search shows a menu that allows you to switch between Contains and Starts With, with the latter being the default.

There is a hidden setting to change the default to Contains.

1. Quit Safari. (Safari menu > Quit or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>)
2. Open Terminal. (Applications > Utilities > Terminal)
3. Copy/paste the following line *exactly* and press <kbd>Return</kbd>:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.Safari FindOnPageMatchesWordStartsOnly -bool FALSE
   ```

The next time you run Safari, substring matching (which is what you are trying to do) should work correctly.

Comment: I must admit thats a very strange design decision. I've never seen a text search UX that defaults to word prefix search. Now I'm thinking on how many searches I missed before just because I didn't know about that default.

Comment: Surprise: this doesn't work for Safari 13.0.2 in macOS 10.15. But dropdown showing "Contains/Starts With" switch which appears when you click small magnifying glass icon in field where you enter search term - still works.

Comment: omg thank you. Like @MaxO said, I must've missed thousands of searches because of this "default" "feature"/bug. I knew Safari was gaslighting me somehow, I never had a problem w/Chrome.